# how to set array in filter parameter?

Tags: angularjs

I have next list

```
var companies = [
    {
        id:1,
        members : ['alex', 'john','nick']
    },
    {
        id:2,
        members : ['alex', 'john','nick']
    },
    {
        id:3,
        members : ['alex']
    },
    {
        id:3,
        members : ['nick']
    }
]

<div  ng-repeat="item in companies | filter:itemFilter track by item._id "></div>
```

I want to pass next parameters into filter:

```
scope.itemFilter = {members: ['john','nick']
```

But it doesn't work.
what to do?

Answer (score 0):

The expression you put as parameter can also be a function :

```
scope.itemFilter = function(value /*, index, array*/){
     return (value.members.indexOf("john") >= 0 || value.members.indexOf("nick") >= 0);
};
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new filter for your requirements.

Controller:

```
$scope.names = ['john','nick'];
```

Filter:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .filter('nameFilter', nameFilter);

    function nameFilter() {
        return nameFilter;

        function nameFilter(list, names) {
            var checkName = function (arr) {
                var members = names;
                members.map(function (val) {
                    if (arr.indexOf(val) !== -1) return true;
                });
                return false;
            }
            return list.filter(checkName)
        }
    }
})();
```

View:

```
<div  ng-repeat="item in companies | nameFilter(names) track by item._id "></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set filter dynamically,

```
app.filter('expenditurePayeeFilter', [
  function($filter) {
    return function(inputArray, searchArray) {
      if (!angular.isDefined(searchArray) || searchArray.length == 0) {
        return inputArray;
      }
      var data = [];
      var arrayContains = function(arr,sub) {
        var self = this;
        var result = sub.filter(function(item) {
          return arr.indexOf(item) > -1;
        });
        return sub.length === result.length;
      }
      angular.forEach(inputArray, function(item) {
        if(arrayContains(item.members,searchArray))
          data.push(item);
      });
      return data;
    };
  }
]);
```

This function checks whether sub-array contains/includes in main array

```
  var arrayContains = function(arr,sub) {
    var self = this;
    var result = sub.filter(function(item) {
      return arr.indexOf(item) > -1;
    });
    return sub.length === result.length;
  }
```

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.filter('expenditurePayeeFilter', [
  function($filter) {
    return function(inputArray, searchArray) {
      if (!angular.isDefined(searchArray) || searchArray.length == 0) {
        return inputArray;
      }
      var data = [];
      var arrayContains = function(arr,sub) {
        var self = this;
        var result = sub.filter(function(item) {
          return arr.indexOf(item) > -1;
        });
        return sub.length === result.length;
      }
      angular.forEach(inputArray, function(item) {
        if(arrayContains(item.members,searchArray))
          data.push(item);
      });
      return data;
    };
  }
]);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.itemFilter = ['john', 'nick'];
  $scope.companies = [{
    id: 1,
    members: ['alex', 'john', 'nick']
  }, {
    id: 2,
    members: ['alex', 'john', 'nick']
  }, {
    id: 3,
    members: ['alex']
  }, {
    id: 3,
    members: ['nick']
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in companies | expenditurePayeeFilter:itemFilter">
    {{item.id}}::{{item.members}}
  </div>
</div>
```